# Customizar páginas individuais no WordPress

Tags: wordpress, layout

O WordPress oferece a opção de customizar os Temas ao vivo através do botão personalizar. Porém, eu gostaria de ter essa mesma opção ao vivo de customizar as páginas individualmente, sem ter necessidade de ser igual ao tema. Exemplo: mudar o plano de fundo, cor de fonte e dentre outras coisas que desejar.

No Wordpress tem essa solução, ou plugin?

Tentei usar digitando o endereço: `http://dominio.com/wp/wp-admin/customize.php?url= http://dominio.com/wp/pagina-exemplo`

Até abre para edição, porém muda todo o tema.

[image: Tela de Personalização]

Comment: Excelente idéia!

Comment: Procure o plugin de construção de tema em tempo real, ( LIve Composer ). Somente procure sobre ele. Acredito que te ajudará.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ainda não existe esse tipo de edição mais inteligente implementado de forma nativa no WordPress, mas acredito que dentro de pouco tempo exista.

Quando você usa o customizador para personalizar cores por exemplo, é inseriro no código HTML do seu template, uma ou mais tags `style` com os códigos prontos baseados nas opções que você definiu no editor.

Vendo o tema usado no print da sua pergunta, vejo que é o `Twenty Twelve`, usei ele em localhost também para verificar melhor e te dar a resposta específica para o seu caso, então vamos lá, esse tema gera uma tag `style` para a cor do cabeçalho e uma para o fundo do blog mais ou menos assim no HTML:

```
<style type="text/css" id="twentytwelve-header-css">.....</style>
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">.....</style>
```

Dentro das tags `style` contém o código CSS que você configurou através do editor, depois que você configurar, abra o seu **WordPress** em localhost e veja o código fonte e procure por esses trechos que mencionei e você vai encontrá-los.

Já que você quer definir cores de cabeçalho e imagem de fundo específicas para as páginas e publicações, isso pode ser feito através de condicionais do **WordPress** como `is_page`, `is_single`, `is_category`, `is_tag` entre outras que servem para realizar verificações na página atual.

Abaixo segue um código de exemplo que testei em localhost e tive que criar 3 páginas (**página de exemplo**, **contato**, **sobre**) para poder ver o resultado e está funcionando corretamente, o código é pequeno e apenas contém as opções já nativas desse tema em questão, mas caso tenha conhecimento de CSS, você pode customizar tudo que quiser, recomendo que insira ele abaixo do código `<?php wp_head(); ?>` no arquivo `header.php` do seu template:

```
<?php if ( is_page( 'pagina-de-exemplo' ) ) { ?>

<style type="text/css">

.site-header h1 a, .site-header h2 { color: #dd3333; }
body.custom-background { background-color: #3333dd; }

</style>

<?php } elseif ( is_page( 'contato' ) ) { ?>

<style type="text/css">

.site-header h1 a, .site-header h2 { color: #33dd33; }
body.custom-background { background-color: #dd3333; }

</style>

<?php } elseif ( is_page( 'sobre' ) ) { ?>

<style type="text/css">

.site-header h1 a, .site-header h2 { color: #3333dd; }
body.custom-background { background-color: #33dd33; }

</style>

<?php } ?>
```

- [Tags Condicionais](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)